# Content visible in header when scrolled

Tags: html, css

I have a simple header and body php page. However, when I scroll, the content is visible behind the 'Hi' header.

```
<style type="text/css">
  #header {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
  }
  #body {
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
  }

</style>

<header> 

<div class="fixed">   
  <h1>  Hi <?php $_POST ["user"] ?>  </h1> 
    <p>Your list: </p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</header>

<body>

<link href="stylesheet2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


  <?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?> 

  <?php

echo "<p> You are gluten free<br/>"; //AND THE REST OF THE CONTENT?>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I have tried a few things. I think it might be a really simple answer. I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: This question is not PHP related, please use the correct tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I would like to say that your markup is completely invalid, you cannot use `header` tag outside the `body` tag, so first nest that inside the `body` and as far as the content visibility goes, you need to assign some `background-color` to your `header` element.

Also, place the `link` tag between `head` tags, pick up the document level `style` block, place it in between the `body` tags, or between the `head` tags.

---

Not related to the answer, but just kinda bonus, if you resize your browser, you will see that `position: fixed;` element will scroll horizontally as well, inorder to prevent that, consider using jQuery, which will set the element to `position: absolute;` and on horizontal scroll, it will keep changing the `top` property value.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hbkdt/) ([Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12545085/1542290))

Comment: @AndrewSmith what you want? you want your header to be static? if yes than remove positioned fixed